# Is this a clang bug? anonymous structs for typedef

Tags: c, struct, clang, typedef, anonymous-struct

I had this typedef for a struct like

```
typedef struct { double x, y; } ACVector;
```

and when I look at instances of this in the debugger I get very strange output something like

```
(lldb) p _translation
(ACVector) $1 = {
  (double) x = -5503.61
  (double) y = -5503.61
  (CLLocationDegrees) latitude = -5503.61
  (CLLocationDegrees) longitude = -1315.67
}

(lldb) p _translation.x
(double) $2 = -5503.61
(lldb) p _translation.y
(double) $2 = -5503.61
```

if I change the definition of ACVector to

```
typedef struct ACVector { double x, y; } ACVector;
```

and do the same in the debugger I get what I expect

```
(lldb) p _translation
(ACVector) $1 = {
  (double) x = -5503.61
  (double) y = -1315.67
}
```

It is legal to use anonymous structs for typedef

### OK so more code

the declaration of _translation is as an instance variable

```
ACVector    _translation;
```

I use this function to initialise the variable

```
ACVector ACVectorMake( double x, double y )
{
    ACVector    r;
    r.x = x;
    r.y = y;
    return r;
}
```

Like this

```
_translation = ACVectorMake( d[xp[0]].x-s[xp[0]].x,  d[xp[0]].y-s[xp[0]].y );
```

Originally it was a

```
ACVector ACVectorMake( double x, double y )
{
    return (ACVector){x,y};
}
```

And where would the latitude and longitude elements come from in the debugger output, mind you you could not access them individually

### More info in response to ACVector defined somewhere else

I have two defines

```
#define ACVectorZero        (ACVector){(double)0.0,(double)0.0}
#define ACVectorUnit        (ACVector){(double)1.0,(double)1.0}
```

which interestingly are followed directly by

```
#define ACDegreesFromDegreesMinutesSeconds( d, m, s )                       (CLLocationDegrees)(d+m/60.0+s/3600.0)
#define ACLocationFromDegreesMinutesSeconds( yd, ym, ys, xd, xm, xs )       (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ACDegreesFromDegreesMinutesSeconds( xd, xm, xs ), ACDegreesFromDegreesMinutesSeconds( yd, ym, ys )}
```

which could explain perhaps explain the occurrence of latitude and longitude in ACVector

Did a search for every occurrence of ACVector including in libraries, couldn't find any other occurrences of ACVector being defined

#### This is all using Xcode 4.5 Gold Master

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any conflicting types, or multiple definitions of `ACVector`?

Comment: Regarding your question about using anonymous structures for typedefs, that is not only legal, it's quite common.

Comment: Print `sizeof _translation`, too.

Comment: p sizeof _translation equals 16 as expected

Comment: @NathanDay My best guess is still that there is another definition of ACVector, somewhere in the code, which the debuger is using.

Comment: That gives me

Best match found in /Users/nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MSDMap-hkwiwqygokqczkfkaypjmamflwga/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECR Map.app/ECR Map:
id = {0x0001f111}, name = "ACVector", byte-size = 16, decl = ACMapToPixelTranslator.m:12, clang_type = "typedef ACVector"
     typedef 'ACVector': id = {0x0001f0ee}, name = "<anonymous struct>", byte-size = 16, decl = ACMapToPixelTranslator.h:12, clang_type = "struct {
    double x;
    double y;
}"

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you probably use `struct ACVector _translation` instead of `ACVector _translation` in the declaration of your variable.

Please show us more code.

Comment: @Mr.32 Not really. This is C. You can have both `struct Something` and `Something` as non-conflicting types.

Comment: @Mr.32 But that won't happen if there is a `struct ACVector` somewhere else in the code. My guess is that there is.

Answer (score 0):

According to

[C language standard n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Under 6.7.4 Function specifiers

```
12
The one exception allows the value of a restricted pointer to be carried
 out of the block in which it (or, more
precisely, the ordinary identifier used to designate it) is declared when
that block finishes execution.
```

For
    example, this permits new_vector to return a vector.

```
typedef struct { int n; float * restrict v; } vector;
vector new_vector(int n)
{
vector t;
t.n = n;
t.v = malloc(n * sizeof (float));
return t;
}
```

So yes now we can say

**It is legal to use anonymous structs for typedef**

So now you are doing something else which case unexpected behaviour for you..

Comment: I was pretty sure it was, but I thought it was possible I was getting confused with some GNU extension perhaps.

Comment: in such condition always find what is true in draft document of c and then go ahead